# How to avoid WARNING message "already attached to project, ignoring duplicate"

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I've tried to avoid the maven warning message which comes from assembly plug in (I compile 2 jar files which are compiled from the same module)

Part of my pom.xml :

maven-jar-plugin
            2.3.1
            
                
                    default-jar
                    none

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.5</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>MockFX</id>
                <configuration>
                    <finalName>MockFX</finalName>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>mock.DSlauncher.FX.FX_DataSourceLauncher</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>single</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>

            <execution>
                <id>MockFutures</id>
                <configuration>
                    <finalName>MockFutures</finalName>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>mock.DSlauncher.Futures.Futures_DataSourceLauncher</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>single</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

During the compilation process I'm getting the next WARNING msg :

```
[WARNING] Artifact com.my.company:UAT-Mock:jar:jar-with-dependencies:1.0 already attached to project, ignoring duplicate
```

What should I add to pom.xml in order to avoid the warning ?

Thanks

Comment: You are trying to execute the same goal `single` with a descriptor `jar-with-dependencies` which produces the same artifacts. You need to configure `<
appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>` in one of your executions and set a classifier via `<classifier>second</classifier>`...

Comment: @khmarbaise thanks for your reply , I've added the <appendAssemblyId> tag , but now I'm getting the next WARNING : Configuration options: 'appendAssemblyId' is set to false, and 'classifier' is missing.  I've added a classifier tag as well , but It didnt help , and the warning is still there

Answer (score 3):

Just add `<attach>false</attach>` to the configuration of both executions